# Managing an ArrayList with GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist

My ArrayList of Books (defined in another class) is not accessible by my listeners further down:-

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {

//bunch of JFrame coding

    public GUI() {

//bunch of GUI setup code

        ArrayList<Book> booklist = new ArrayList <Book> ();
        booklist.add(new Book("White Fang2", "1963", "John Buchan", "123"));
    }
}

class event implements ActionListener {
    event() {
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        if (op.equals("Show Library")) {

            for (Book book : booklist) {
                GUI.this.libraryResult.setText(libraryResult.getText() + book.getTitle());
            }

        }//close Show library button
    }//close ClearListener
}//Close GUI Class
```

My ActionListener code cannot 'see' booklist ("Cannot resolve symbol booklist"). If I try and create a local variable booklist in ActionListener then it is empty.

What am I doing wrong? Where or how should I create the ArrayList so that it can be populated and accessed by my listeners?

Comment: Why not simply give your GUI a Library field, pass a valid reference to the one Library instance to that field, and then your button's ActionListeners will have access to this field?

Comment: My problem is I don't see where you create your Library instance, where you want to create it and what field holds it, nor how this relates to where you create your GUI. A [mre] would help in this regard -- make it a simplified version or your current program.

Comment: Note that I see that the Book class creates a Library instance -- that doesn't really make sense, does it?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels. You're right, the Library instance in Book was some testing, should have removed it. When you say you can't see my Library instance, you're right. Because I can't seem to populate it as a separate Class, I have resorted to creating an ArrayList directly in ActionPerformed. I don't care where I create it, but as I can't add to it I am trying to understand if that is a coding error, or I have created an ArrayList in the wrong place.

Comment: Creating a Library instance or an `ArrayList<Book>` within the actionPerformed and assigning it doesn't make logical sense since the instance will be visible no where else, and will disappear and be useless once the method has completed. That is why the variable should probably be an instance field of the GUI class making it visible throughout that class's instance methods.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thank you. That is what I have been thinking is the error. My problem is that if I make eg ArrayList<Book> booklist = new ArrayList <Book> (); inside my GUI class: 
(1) I cannot add books to it ( booklist.add(new Book("White Fang", "1963", "John Buchan", "123")); will show the 'add' in red; and 
(2) none of the actionPerformed button code can 'see' booklist, making any attempt to work with the ArrayList impossible.

You have hit the nail on the head and confirmed what I have been feeling, but I am lost as to how or where to make this ArrayList populate and be visible

Comment: Then the problem is why can't your listeners see the field. It should be visible, or if not, then a reference should be passed into where it is needed. Your problems that you're running into are not GUI or Swing specific, but rather mainly understanding how references are used in Java and how to pass references to where and when they are needed. You need to create and post your [mre] for us to really see what you are doing wrong (as mentioned above already)

Comment: Please [edit] and improve your question's code

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I really appreciate the helpful feedback. I will try and reformulate my question.

Comment: Please comment back if you do edit your question

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels. I have edited my question down to the minimum focus point. I'm hoping you can see it without me having to create a new question. The system implies that editing it will remove the "closed" status, but that has not seemed to have happened.

Comment: You're declaring the ArrayList variable inside the constructor. Think about that for a bit.... answer please: if you do this, where is the variable visible? How could you solve this? You will also want to look up "variable scope". Also, side note: this is not a valid [mre], but you probably don't need one to solve this basic issue, but for future questions, you will want to look up the MRE link and internalize it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply @HovercraftFullOfEels. You asked the question that solved my problem. I declare the ArrayList in the GUI class and populate it in the constructor. I have spent 4 days on this. If it were covid-appropriate I would kiss you.